# creating a linked list with 100 nodes each containing a random number C

Tags: c, for-loop, linked-list, codeblocks

**I'm trying to understand linked lists and I want to make one that contains 100 nodes containing random numbers.. My codeblocks says that there are no errors but my program crashes when I try to run it. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
    int number;
    struct node * next;
}Node;

typedef Node*Nodeptr;

int main() //creating the linked list  
{
    int i;
    Nodeptr head = NULL;
    Nodeptr here = head;
    Nodeptr newnode = NULL;
    head = malloc(sizeof(Node));

    if(head == NULL){ //was told build the 1st node out of the loop
        return 1;
    }
    for (i=0; i<100; i++){
         newnode->number = rand()%100;
         newnode->next = NULL;
         here->next = newnode;
         here = here->next;
    }

    printf("%d, %d, %p\n", i, here->number, here->next);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first line of the `for` loop needs to create a new `Node` using `malloc()`

Comment: `newnode->number` : `newnode` is `NULL`. So It can't dereference.

Comment: Also, assign `here` after you `malloc()` `head`.

Comment: these two lines are incompatable: `struct node *newnode = NULL;` and `newnode->number = rand()%100;`  because it is set to NULL and never updated.

Comment: You are thinking about use of `newnode` wrong. You should allocate `newnode` each time and check `if (head == NULL) head = newnode; /* for first node */ else {... iterate to last node and then last->next = newnode ...}`

Comment: 'I don't know what I am doing wrong.' well, not using a debugger, for one:(

Answer (score 1):

here is a version of the code that checks for errors, and properly initializes each node

```
#include <stdio.h>   // printf(), NULL
#include <stdlib.h>  // malloc()

struct node
{
    int number;
    struct node * next;
};



int main( void ) //creating the linked list
{
    int i;
    struct node *head = malloc(sizeof( struct node ));
    if(head == NULL)
    { //was told build the 1st node out of the loop
        perror( "malloc for for node failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    head->next = NULL;
    head->number = rand()%100;
    printf("node: %2.2d, %2.2d, %p\n", 0, head->number, head->next);

    struct node *here = head;

    for (i=1; i<100; i++)
    {
        here->next = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
        if( !(here->next) )
        {
            perror( "malloc failed" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, malloc successful

        here = here->next;
        here->number = rand()%100;
        printf("node: %2.2d, %2.2d, %p\n", i, here->number, here->next);
    }

    return 0; // << in modern compilers, this line not needed
              // << when returning from 'main()' and value is 0
} // end function: main
```

and the typical output is:

```
node: 00, 83, (nil)
node: 01, 86, (nil)
node: 02, 77, (nil)
node: 03, 15, (nil)
node: 04, 93, (nil)
node: 05, 35, (nil)
node: 06, 86, (nil)
node: 07, 92, (nil)
node: 08, 49, (nil)
node: 09, 21, (nil)
node: 10, 62, (nil)
node: 11, 27, (nil)
node: 12, 90, (nil)
node: 13, 59, (nil)
node: 14, 63, (nil)
node: 15, 26, (nil)
node: 16, 40, (nil)
node: 17, 26, (nil)
node: 18, 72, (nil)
node: 19, 36, (nil)
node: 20, 11, (nil)
node: 21, 68, (nil)
node: 22, 67, (nil)
node: 23, 29, (nil)
node: 24, 82, (nil)
node: 25, 30, (nil)
node: 26, 62, (nil)
node: 27, 23, (nil)
node: 28, 67, (nil)
node: 29, 35, (nil)
node: 30, 29, (nil)
node: 31, 02, (nil)
node: 32, 22, (nil)
node: 33, 58, (nil)
node: 34, 69, (nil)
node: 35, 67, (nil)
node: 36, 93, (nil)
node: 37, 56, (nil)
node: 38, 11, (nil)
node: 39, 42, (nil)
node: 40, 29, (nil)
node: 41, 73, (nil)
node: 42, 21, (nil)
node: 43, 19, (nil)
node: 44, 84, (nil)
node: 45, 37, (nil)
node: 46, 98, (nil)
node: 47, 24, (nil)
node: 48, 15, (nil)
node: 49, 70, (nil)
node: 50, 13, (nil)
node: 51, 26, (nil)
node: 52, 91, (nil)
node: 53, 80, (nil)
node: 54, 56, (nil)
node: 55, 73, (nil)
node: 56, 62, (nil)
node: 57, 70, (nil)
node: 58, 96, (nil)
node: 59, 81, (nil)
node: 60, 05, (nil)
node: 61, 25, (nil)
node: 62, 84, (nil)
node: 63, 27, (nil)
node: 64, 36, (nil)
node: 65, 05, (nil)
node: 66, 46, (nil)
node: 67, 29, (nil)
node: 68, 13, (nil)
node: 69, 57, (nil)
node: 70, 24, (nil)
node: 71, 95, (nil)
node: 72, 82, (nil)
node: 73, 45, (nil)
node: 74, 14, (nil)
node: 75, 67, (nil)
node: 76, 34, (nil)
node: 77, 64, (nil)
node: 78, 43, (nil)
node: 79, 50, (nil)
node: 80, 87, (nil)
node: 81, 08, (nil)
node: 82, 76, (nil)
node: 83, 78, (nil)
node: 84, 88, (nil)
node: 85, 84, (nil)
node: 86, 03, (nil)
node: 87, 51, (nil)
node: 88, 54, (nil)
node: 89, 99, (nil)
node: 90, 32, (nil)
node: 91, 60, (nil)
node: 92, 76, (nil)
node: 93, 68, (nil)
node: 94, 39, (nil)
node: 95, 12, (nil)
node: 96, 26, (nil)
node: 97, 86, (nil)
node: 98, 94, (nil)
node: 99, 39, (nil)
```

so, perhaps you would like to display the address of the current node rather than the contents of the 'next' field.

then the `printf()` statements would be:

```
printf("node: %2.2d, %2.2d, %p\n", 0, head->number, head);
```

and

```
printf("node: %2.2d, %2.2d, %p\n", i, here->number, here);
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating a linked list with 100 random numbers can be done in the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} node;

node *newNode(int data) {
    node *new_node = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
    new_node->data = data;    
    new_node->next = NULL;;
    return new_node;
}

node *insert_node(node *root, int data) {
    if (root == NULL)
        return newNode(data);
    else {
        node *cur;    
        cur = insert_node(root->next, data);
        root->next = cur;    
    }
    return root;
}

void print(node *np) {
    if (np) {
        printf("(%d)", np->data);
        print(np->next);
    }
}

int main() {
    int T = 100;
    node *root = NULL;
    while (T-- > 0) {
        int r = rand() % 200;
        root = insert_node(root, r);
    }
    print(root);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Please try it [online](http://ideone.com/Arp1CH).

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `newnode` and `head` are a bit reversed. All you need do is allocate `newnode` each tine and then either create a *new* list (e.g. assign `head=newnode` or iterate over your list and assign `newnode` at the end of list. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct node {
    int number;
    struct node *next;
} node;

int main (void) {

    srand (time (NULL));

    node *head = NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        node *newnode = malloc (sizeof *newnode);
        if (!newnode) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: memory exhausted node '%d'.\n", i);
            break;
        }

        newnode->number = rand() % 100;
        newnode->next = NULL;

        if (!head)          /* new list, assign to head */
            head = newnode;
        else {              /* otherwise iterate and add to end */
            node *iter = head;
            for (; iter->next; iter = iter->next) {}
            iter->next = newnode;
        }
    }

    int j = 0;  /* output list (including pointer addresses) */
    for (node *iter = head; iter; iter = iter->next)
        printf ("node[%3d] : %3d,       addr: %p, next: %p\n",
                j++, iter->number, (void*)iter, (void*)iter->next);

    /* free list memory */
    node *victim = NULL;    /* node to delete */
    for (node *iter = head; iter; iter = iter->next) {
        if (victim)     /* cannot delete until after loop increment */
            free (victim);
        victim = iter;  /* so save node as victim, delete next iteration */
    }
    if (victim)         /* free last node */
        free (victim);

    return 0;
}
```

**Note** don't forget to `free` all memory you allocate.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/llmin
node[  0] :  91,       addr: 0x2228010, next: 0x2228030
node[  1] :  48,       addr: 0x2228030, next: 0x2228050
node[  2] :  18,       addr: 0x2228050, next: 0x2228070
node[  3] :  97,       addr: 0x2228070, next: 0x2228090
node[  4] :  15,       addr: 0x2228090, next: 0x22280b0
node[  5] :  46,       addr: 0x22280b0, next: 0x22280d0
node[  6] :  93,       addr: 0x22280d0, next: 0x22280f0
node[  7] :  22,       addr: 0x22280f0, next: 0x2228110
node[  8] :  17,       addr: 0x2228110, next: 0x2228130
node[  9] :   6,       addr: 0x2228130, next: 0x2228150
node[ 10] :  64,       addr: 0x2228150, next: 0x2228170
...
node[ 90] :  57,       addr: 0x2228b50, next: 0x2228b70
node[ 91] :  64,       addr: 0x2228b70, next: 0x2228b90
node[ 92] :  91,       addr: 0x2228b90, next: 0x2228bb0
node[ 93] :  66,       addr: 0x2228bb0, next: 0x2228bd0
node[ 94] :  13,       addr: 0x2228bd0, next: 0x2228bf0
node[ 95] :  89,       addr: 0x2228bf0, next: 0x2228c10
node[ 96] :  73,       addr: 0x2228c10, next: 0x2228c30
node[ 97] :  42,       addr: 0x2228c30, next: 0x2228c50
node[ 98] :  79,       addr: 0x2228c50, next: 0x2228c70
node[ 99] :  23,       addr: 0x2228c70, next: (nil)
```

Look it over and let me know if you have any questions.